# Is there a way to access post-parameter command content in discord.py using CommandTree

Tags: discord.py

I have a slash command which I essentially define like this:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(
    name="mycmd",
    description="...",
    guild=discord.Object(id=serverId)
)
@app_commands.autocomplete(...)
async def mycmd(
    interaction: discord.Interaction,
    arg1: str,
    arg2: str,
    extra: str = ''
):
```

Is there a way to access any subsequent content in the command? E.g. if someone runs `/mycmd [foo] [bar] baz bam bap` where `foo` and `bar` are arg1 and arg2, is there a way to access "baz bam bap"? In discord.py docs I see references to `*` or `*args` but those don't seem to work with this stuff, maybe only the bot module. Currently I have an optional "extra" parameter people can specify, but I would rather just grab everything without that parameter.

I have no idea if this is the correct or modern way to implement slash commands; I cobbled it together from docs and samples. discord.py is kind of a confusing mess. But it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct way to implement your idea. Let's break down the code,

```
@tree.command(
    name="mycmd",
    description="...",
    guild=discord.Object(id=serverId)
)
@app_commands.autocomplete(...)
async def mycmd(
    interaction: discord.Interaction,
    arg1: str,
    arg2: str,
    extra: str = ''
):
    ...
```

`extra` is an optional argument. A user can run `/mycmd arg1: a arg2: b extra: baz bam bap`.

Slash commands take in parameters, such as `arg1: a`. Unlike prefix commands which are positional `!mycmd a b baz bam bap`.

Anything typed after the command prompts like `/mycmd arg1: a arg2: b  something` will not be sent to the bot.

For something like this, I would suggest using prefix commands;

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(...)


@bot.command()
async def mycmd(ctx, arg1, arg2, *, extra):
    ...
```

Depending on your prefix, this can be ran with `!mycmd arg1 arg2 baz bam bap`.

Comment: "Anything typed after the command prompts [...] will not be sent to the bot." Perfect, that's what I was wondering. Thank you!